# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_userdata()

Tags: plugins, wp-query

I am getting this error when I call this method `$query->the_post();`. I am trying to get the post id to get the post meta data. Accessing the `$post->ID` from `global post` return the current page id, but I need the post id for searching purpose.

[You can see the error as image here](http://prntscr.com/h19h2u)

```
function search_form_submit(){

$task_name  = isset($_GET['taskname']) ? $_GET['taskname'] : '';
$meta_key = 'wp_tasks';

$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'tasks',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => $meta_key,
            'value' => $task_name,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                    ),
                );


$query = new WP_Query($args);
global $post;

if($query->have_posts()){

    $query->the_post();

    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID,$meta_key,true);
     }
 }

 $tasks_obj = new tasks();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
  $tasks_obj->search_form_submit();
 }
```

Comment: Where is this code being used? What hook?

Comment: Have a look on links may be helpful to explain why you got this error https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126206/80247

Comment: if you use the while loop, the post ID is not required. It shows meta values for the current post. Just use get_post_meta($meta_key);

Comment: I am not using any hook, just submitting the form on this function,  function search_form_submit(){

Comment: For context, `get_userdata()` is used inside `setup_postdata()`, which is used inside `the_post()`. Since it’s pluggabke you can’t use it before `plugins_loaded`. Hence my question about the hook.

Comment: I just updated the code above @JacobPeattie  not using any hook for that

Comment: Well you need to. Why don't you want to use a hook. This is *WordPress*. Everything is hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, forms should be handled on `init` action or later (mainly in a plugin file, maybe in the theme's functions.php file, never in a tempalte file), so you can have access to WP functions.

```
add_action( 'init', 'search_form_submit' );
function search_form_submit(){

    $task_name  = isset($_GET['taskname']) ? $_GET['taskname'] : '';
    $meta_key = 'wp_tasks';

    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'tasks',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => $meta_key,
                'value' => $task_name,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            ),
                        ),
                    );


    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query->have_posts()){

        $query->the_post();

        $data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$meta_key,true);
         }
     }

     $tasks_obj = new tasks();

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
      $tasks_obj->search_form_submit();
     }

}
```